# Find if the database COLLATION is case sensitive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I tell if the database collation is case sensitive? Is there a better way than looking for "CS"/"BIN" in collation name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Database_Name', 'Collation')
```

See if it returns something like `Latin_General_CS_AS` if it has `CS` in the collation it means it is Case Sensitive and if the collation name has `CI` it means it is Case Insensative.

Comment: Looks like my question has this answer. But it would have been much better if COLLATIONPROPERTY function supported IsCaseSensitive. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem a better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'a' = N'A' 
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS IsCaseSensitive
```

Comment: this will work for some databases. But not all alphabets has the same letters. For greek this would not show the desired result

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, do you mean that there is a collation where `N'a' = N'A'` but `N'Ω' <> N'ω'`

Comment: No, that is not what i mean, in some alphabets A does not exists. As far as i can tell, your check would not work with the greek alphabet. I made the same mistake on a different question and got downvoted.

Comment: Just because a given alphabet doesn't have a certain letter doesn't mean that the collation doesn't deal with it. A concrete example using Greek: `SELECT CASE WHEN N'a' COLLATE Greek_100_CS_AS = N'A'  COLLATE Greek_100_CS_AS THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsCaseSensitive` Then try running the same query with Greek_100_CI_AS instead of Greek_100_CS_AS.

Comment: This is no doubt one way to do it. But one has to run this query in context of a database. So N Queries for N databases. I would rather go with SELECT name, collation_name from sys.databases and look for CS in it, if that's accurate.